# I want to invoke a store procedure from jdbctemplate and need the pk generated in store procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

```
    Create procedure College.Create_Student

        @Roll Number VARCHAR(7) = NULL,
        @Name VARCHAR(35) = NULL,
        @Phone VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
        @Email VARCHAR(20) = NULL

# Insert into Student Table and return the primary key
```

And in java Class

```
String sql = "{call college.create_student(?,?,?,?)}";
String studentUniqueNum = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,
new Object[] { roll_num,name,phone,email},String.class);
```

I am trying to get primary key generated in store procedure . Please help

PS : I am doing it first time.

Answer (score 0):

For simple procedures you may use jdbcTemplate's update method:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call college.create_student(?, ?, ?, ?)", param1, param2, param3, param4);
```

This method will return your primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but thats not what i was looking for . After so much of searching ... I am looking for an answer with the output parameter in the store procedure and how to retrieve it in the java with jdbctemplate

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve it

1. Create a pojo class which holds the Name(String) and Type(int) needs to match with store procedure input variable and another pojo
   class for output with the same parameters.
2. In the service class, create a 2 List one for input and one for output the above created pojo class.
3. Instantiate the pojo and add the name and type which should be the name matching with the store procedure input and type parameter
   for all the input variable.
4. Create a function which extends the StoredProcedure of spring framework and takes jdbctemaplate ,procedure name,input and output
   list .Iterate over this list and use the delcareparameter of spring
   frame work to create the Sql parameter for each and every input and
   out parameters and then compile.
5. Create a hashMap for the mapping the input parameters with the values where key is the input variable name and value was the actual input.
6. Final step  use the execute method of spring and pass the hashmap created in the above step.
7. Final result again returns a hashmap which actually holds the output param and its value (as mentioned in step 2).